# Where does MATE keep the contents of its application drop down?

Tags: mate-desktop

- Fedora 34
- Xfce 4.12
- mate-desktop-1.26.0-1.fc34.x86_64

I have both Xfce and MATE installed on my desktop.  I choose which one I want at logon.

I have a ton of intellectual property in Xfce's panel 0 and panel 1 popups.  I know were to find them.  I would like to create a Raku program to transfer them over to MATE.  But I can not find where MATE stores its stuff in its Applications drop down.

Anyone know where MATE stores such?  (I am not finding them in dconf.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally the MATE menu displays all `.desktop` app launchers in these directories:

```bsh
/usr/share/applications/
/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/
```

the configuration file for hiding specific apps is in

```bsh
/home/$USER/.config/menus/mate-applications.menu
```

On my machine it currently looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Menu
  PUBLIC '-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN'
  'http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd'>
<Menu>
    <Name>Applications</Name>
    <MergeFile type="parent">/etc/xdg/menus/mate-applications.menu</MergeFile>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Accessories</Name>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>hplip.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <AppDir>/home/kunruh/.local/share/applications</AppDir>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>kvantummanager.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>manjaro-documentation.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>plank.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>stoken-gui.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>stoken-gui-small.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>redshift-gtk.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Internet</Name>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>bssh.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <AppDir>/home/kunruh/.local/share/applications</AppDir>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>bvnc.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Other</Name>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>hp-uiscan.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <AppDir>/home/kunruh/.local/share/applications</AppDir>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Multimedia</Name>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>mpv.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <AppDir>/home/kunruh/.local/share/applications</AppDir>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>qv4l2.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>qvidcap.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>System</Name>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>avahi-discover.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <AppDir>/home/kunruh/.local/share/applications</AppDir>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>lstopo.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>uxterm.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>xterm.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Development</Name>
        <Exclude>
            <Filename>yad-icon-browser.desktop</Filename>
        </Exclude>
        <AppDir>/home/kunruh/.local/share/applications</AppDir>
    </Menu>
</Menu>
```

Otherwise if you want to add menu entries you simply have to create a `.desktop` file and put it in the right locations.
I made a [post-installation script](https://github.com/FreaxMATE/matify) for Manjaro to fit my needs, maybe you find things you also wanted to customize :)

[freedesktop specifications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html)

Comment: It should also be noted, that autostart applications are taken from `~/.config/autostart` and `/etc/xdg/autostart` respectively.

Comment: This is the only answer that put any effort in.

Answer (score 1):

The menu items in application menu can be kept in `~/.local/share/applications/`. It's the standard directory where all user level `.desktop` launchers are kept.

Answer (score -1):

Try `grep -r '\.desktop' /etc/*` That will show you everywhere .desktop files are used, which is what menu entries are in most cases. But certain desktops do not observe the convention to put configurations in `/etc` so you ca also search `home` like so: `grep -r '\.desktop' /home/user/.?*`

But the output may be a bit sloppy/

Comment: It is giving me the structure of the entries, but not the entry data: cat /etc/xdg/menus/mate-applications.menu.  The global structure will not have the spec user's settings

Comment: In other words, I want to write a program to add entries to the "users" applications menu.  But I need to know where they are first.  Not the global templates.

Comment: Desktop files can be found in many places - not just `/etc/*` - try using the 'locate' command.

Comment: Yes, the actual .desktop files are actually not in /etc, but the configuration files for the menus are, and they list which desktop files are in the various menus. I was unclear.